# Device ineligible in Xcode 6 when device connected powered by iOS 8.1

Tags: ios8, xcode6

Till yesterday my configuration for devices/tools looked as below

```
iOS - 8.0.2 
Xcode - 6.0.1 
OSX - Mavericks
```

I have upgraded by iOS version from 8.0.2 to 8.1 today and when I connect my device to my mac, i am seeing, my device in "Ineligibale Device"

I have looked into similar issues and most of the solution is advised to change the deployment target from 7.0 to 8.0. But I need my deployment target to be on 7.0

I restarted my device and any my mac but still have the same problem. When I disconnect the device and connect it again. I see error message as below in Window->Devices ".. running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode"

This I interpret as Xcode 6.0.1 doesn't support devices with iOS8.1. But this looks weird to me. I looked any Xcode update and Xcode 6.1 is only available to install in Yosemite and not in Mavericks. My check and install in Xcode in Mavericks tells me everything is up to date

Any suggestion on how to solve this one? I don't want to change the deployment target as my app should support both 7.0 and 8.0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to install the Xcode 6.1 update. The 6.0.1 does't support iOS 8.1.

I had the same problem this morning

---

For the same issue in Xcode 6.3 + iOS 8.3, change the destination in *product->destination*

Comment: How to resolve this issue is there any authentic way

Comment: changing the destination in product->destination to My Device has solved the problem.

Comment: And here we are 1 year later: if you have the problem with iOS 9.0, install xcode 7.

Comment: I hate Apple forcing me to upgrade XCode for no obvious reason, which of course forces me to upgrade my Mac OS which I hate doing.

Answer (score 34):

If you meet the same issue in XCode6.3 and iOS8.3, you can try:

Select your iPhone in XCode via Product > Destination (solution found here: http://zachwaugh.me/posts/fixing-xcode-6-3-beta/)

Comment: It works. But, why it shows "ineligible"? I'm afraid that this will cause problem in release product.

Comment: PS: I change deploy target to 8.3 and my device is available again to deployment (I have iOS 8.3 already on my device)

Comment: It seems it is a bug in XCode 6.3 or(and) iOS 8.3. My device is iTouch with iOS 8.3, while my friend use iPhone 5S with iOS 8.3, using XCode 6.3 without this issue.

Comment: definitely sketchy: Xcode 6.3 (6D570) ___ iPhone 6 / iOS 8.3 (12F70)  - accepted ___
iPad Air / iOS 8.3 (12F69) - ineligible … the "8.3 (12F70)" version was not linked in, but a (no longer available?) "8.3 (12F69") version was.

Comment: @bshirley My device: iTouch5 /iOS 8.3 (12F69) , it seems iOS 8.3 (12F69) maybe has this issue.

Comment: it works in that it lets you choose the ineligible device however in some projects I'm having trouble building the debug configuration.

Comment: oddly, yes, i can select and built to it - thanks for pointing that out - reported as bug 20634220

Comment: Update to Last XCode 6.3.1 fix this issue.

Comment: I'm having unavailable sign besides the iPhone icon. Using latest xcode but this but couldn't be fixed

Answer (score 2):

Try to re-install Xcode 6. The new installation will take care of the new iOS 8.1. I just solved the same problem a moment ago. Otherwise, you need to upgrade your OS to Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **update** your XCode to **6.3.2** , this issue is fixed by apple in XCode 6.3.2. So just Update your Xcode and every thing will be fine, you don't need to change your "iOS Deployment Target" settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Xcode 6.4 (Swift 1.2) and iOS 9.0.2.

I found a workaround. First you have to install the next version of XCode (which is Xcode 7.0).

Close all Xcode applications.

Now, if you try to open your old project in the older version you will get the message :"Device ineligible for current OS version".

So you open the newer Xcode version. DO NOT open any project. Then open the old Xcode version (in my case Xcode 6.4) and launch the app. My quess is that the old Xcode version uses the new Xcodes compiler and thats why it allows compilation on the newer device.

Hope this helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this with compatible Xcode and iOS versions (i.e. needing an Xcode update was not the issue).

I resolved it as follows:

1. disconnect your device from Xcode
2. delete the old version of your project application directly on the device
3. reconnect your device to Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my iPhone6+ and was using the "product->destination" workaround.

Then I noticed that I didn't have an iPhone6+ simulator. 
I knew I had had one before, but I added one again.

Then suddenly I had two iPhone6+ simulators. Adding a new one had obviously made Xcode see the missing one. So I deleted one of the iPhone6+ simulators.

Then I noticed that my actual iPhone6+ device was no longer in ineligible devices :)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you update Xcode, you might have lost your iOS Simulators for earlier versions.  Check and redownload the versions for earlier releases.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: (It took me a while to find it again!)  Go into Xcode/Preferences/Downloads. You will see a list of Components.  The iOS Simulators will show whether or not they have been downloaded.